# Pass an anonymous new array to constructor

Tags: typescript

I'm writing some TypeScript code where I want to add an element to my Map. My Map is of type `<number, number[]>`, so when I add a new key-value pair I want to initialize the value to a new empty array.

I know that I can do this:

```
let arr: number[] = [];
myMap.set(i, arr);
```

But I would prefer to do this:

```
myMap.set(i, new number[]);
```

That is how it's done in C# and I was hoping I could do the same in TypeScript, but I'm having trouble finding how to do it. Perhaps I just have the wrong syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `Map` is already typed (eg `Map<number, number[]>`), you don't need to type the arguments.

For a `Map<K, V>`, the signature for `Map.prototype.set()` is

> ```ts
> (method) Map<K, V>.set(key: K, value: V): Map<K, V>
> ```

You can simply pass an empty array which will implicitly satisfy the `number[]` argument type

```ts
const myMap: Map<number, number[]> = new Map();
myMap.set(1, []);
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwLIEMAOAuGq0B4wCucARgKYBOANDISRQNoC6AfDALw2kDu26AFAEoA3AFgAUIhwA6CKSh8AjNSbCgA)

Comment: And the generic types can be supplied at the call site to make it a bit more concise: [`const myMap = new Map<number, number[]>()`](https://tsplay.dev/N5j3dm)

Comment: @jsejcksn it's my Java background showing through

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77649636/pass-an-anonymous-new-array-to-constructor/77649655?noredirect=1#comment136894800_77649655) @Phil There's definitely nothing wrong with explicit type annotations! They provide the best clarity of intent.